# How to only install security updates on debian

Tags: bash, debian, security

Because of the Shell Shock bug I need to make updates on some of our machines.
But I am not sure if all of the packages suggested in `apt-get upgrade` are OK for my system. In other words I am not sure if there are any dependencies.

Our system administrator is not here yet and we cannot contact him.
So my question is, how can I only `apt-get upgrade` the security updates, without having to update everything to the newest available version in debian stable?

**EDIT SOLUTION**
`apt-get install --only-upgrade bash` did the thing for me.
On one of our servers, there was still just Debian Squeeze installed.
Changing **squeeze** to **wheezy** in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then running:
 - `apt-get update`
 - `apt-get install --only-upgrade bash`
installed the fixed bash into this older squeeze system.

Comment: "the newest available version in debian stable" usually *is* the security updates. Stable typically does not change otherwise. There are some packages that are just upgraded to the newest release (e.g. chromium) because it is too hard for the security team to backport security fixes (I think), but you should upgrade that too.

Comment: Hi - I'm also using Squeeze but I'm having trouble getting Bash to upgrade. Can you post the line(s) you changed in the sources.list file, in case the squeeze version is missing from mine?

Comment: I would warn readers *not* to casually change squeeze to wheezy, because that is a major Debian upgrade. The 'wheezy' version of bash depends on newer versions of several core libraries, such as libc6, so you would be risking instability. You are not merely upgrading bash, but shared libraries that almost everything else in Debian will be using. Use Squeeze LTS instead (see answer below).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Squeeze use squeeze-lts if possible! (i386 and amd64 only...)

append this to your sources.list:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

and then run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -t squeeze-lts --only-upgrade bash
```

Here is more detail on squeeze-lts:
https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using

If you *really* want to patch debian lenny check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mattwhite/86de50d30134129e44ef) (but rather consider updating to a newer distro!)

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade <package>
```

If is installed, this will upgrade only the specified package.

Comment: According to the man page for apt-get, the only-upgrade option merely prevents installation of the specified package if it wasn't installed. Note that it does *not* prevent dependencies being installed. (NB The bash package in Debian is always installed, so the option would have no effect.)

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu 12.04 “Precise” and 14.04 “Trusty”, Debian 7 “Wheezy”**

```
apt-get update; apt-get install bash
```

---

**Debian 6 “Squeeze”**

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/squeezelts.list

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50squeezelts

```
APT::Default-Release "squeeze-lts";
```

Then run the update:

```
apt-get update; apt-get install bash
```

---

**Patching older and unsupported systems as Lenny**

```
# Retrieve and install dependencies first
apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential gettext bison

# Get bash 3.2 source
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.2.tar.gz
tar zxvf bash-3.2.tar.gz
cd bash-3.2

# Download and apply all patches
# Includes patches for CVE-2014-6271 (52) *AND* CVE-2014-7169 (53) *AND* Florian Weimer patch (54)
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 54); do
    wget -nv http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.2-patches/bash32-$i
    patch -p0 < bash32-$i
done

# Compile and install to /usr/local/bin/bash
./configure && make
make install

# Point /bin/bash to the new binary
mv /bin/bash /bin/bash.old
ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/bash
```

Comment: Please note: this makes you switch to `squezze-lts`, the next time you run `apt-get upgrade` - Which is a good idea, but something you should be aware of. If you'r building bash-3.2 for older systems, make sure that `make` went well before issuing `make install`

Comment: I agree, execute commands sequentially is better. Caution is never enough.

Answer (score -7):

add this to your sources list:

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main

apt-get update
apt-get install --only-upgrade bash

Comment: This is not a good idea. Next time the OP runs `apt-get upgrade` the entire system will be moved to sid.